# Why is my wife making my items all marked as stolen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I used the infinite inventory glitch for her and accidentally gave her my ebony mail and when I took it back, it was marked as stolen. I tested it out on some dragon scales and a sword and it worked. Later, I tried stealing a potion and was caught. I payed the bounty and lost my ebony mail. Is there any way to fix this?

(Also my wife is Aela just in case it only works with her)

Comment: You used a glitch, and you wonder why things start breaking?

Comment: Are you asking how you can get your armor back and the stolen flag removed?

Comment: I think "Glitch" is your answer here, and I can't imagine that any solution besides "don't abuse the bugs in the game" would help you. (that is, except for using cheats/other glitches)

Comment: stop right there, criminal scum! http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/stop-right-there-criminal-scum

Answer (score 2):

There are some known glitches leading to items being unduly marked as stolen (it happens sometimes when you ask your followers to take everything from a container), but I don't know if they apply to you, since you are not being very specific about what you have done.

Generally speaking though, trying not to run deliberately into software bugs tends to prevent the occurrence of, well, bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Your wife hates you, that's why!

No, upon using glitches, you are messing with the game's script. As we all know, *messing with the script breaks the game, and your character(s). You are messing with the NPC's script as well.*

Answer (score 0):

Abusing glitches in the game, will eventually have a consequence. But to get your items back 'non-stolen', you can sell the item to a fence, exit the window, then reopen the tradewindow (before the merchant resets) and buy it back. It WILL cost you gold, but that's the price of 'whitewashing' stolen items.